# Prevent transposing array when using Java LinkedList in MATLAB

Tags: java, arrays, matlab, linked-list

I am using MATLAB R2015a. When using a Java LinkedList in MATLAB environment, adding row vectors and then retrieving them appears to transpose them into column vectors. For example,

```
import java.util.LinkedList

x = [285   252   100    67]
y = [280   252   107    71;
     374   157    72    48]
z = [284   253   103    68]

LL = LinkedList();

LL.add(x);
LL.add(y);
LL.add(z);

xn = LL.remove()
yn = LL.remove()
zn = LL.remove()
```

`xn, yn and zn` yield the following:

```
xn =

   285
   252
   100
    67


yn =

   280   252   107    71
   374   157    72    48


zn =

   284
   253
   103
    68
```

It only happens when the original vector is strictly `1 x n`. Is there a way to prevent this from happening without adding a checking condition at the end of every `remove()` ?

Comment: This happens also with `x = reshape([285 252 100  67],1,1,[])`. So it appears that the `add` method strips any leading dimensions from the added array (check `LL.toArray` right after `add`), and unlike Matlab it does so even when `x` is a row

Comment: Both of `LL.add({x});` and `LL.add(@()x);` work in Octave AKA `javaMethod ("add", LL, {x})`. so `xn=LL.remove();out = xn{1}` or `xn=LL.remove();out = xn();`

Answer (score 0):

If the linked list happens to be ascii, I recommend just reading the file in line-by-line, and using something like "strsplit()" to separate the values on each line,  and append them to a table with the specified columns.  I use this method to grab Linux/UNIX environment variable values and such.

This can also be done with binary data.